# Spring Data JPA: Pageable query rollbacks transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I've considered an issue when tried to run a @NamedQuery with paging from a Spring Data repository. 
The entity class looks like this:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Customer.findByNamePattern",
        query = "select c from Customer c where c.name like :pattern"
    )    
}) 
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;    
    private String name;
```

The repository interface is:

```
public interface CustomerRepository  extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {    
    //@Query("select c from Customer c where c.name like :pattern")
    Page<Customer> findByNamePattern(@Param("pattern") String pattern,Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I try to call the paged repository methods from a non-transactional context (junit), it works fine.

When I call it from a transactional service method, like:

```
@Service("customerService")
@Transactional
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( CustomerServiceImpl.class.getName());
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Customer> findAllPaged(int pageNum, int pageSize) {     
        PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(pageNum,pageSize);
        return customerRepository.findAll(pr);      
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Customer> findByNamePatternPaged(String keyword, int pageNum, int pageSize) {       
        PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(pageNum,pageSize);
        String pattern = "%"+keyword+"%";
        return customerRepository.findByNamePattern(pattern, pr);       
    }
```

... calling `findAllPaged()`works fine again.

However when I try to call the method which should use the named query I always get an exception :

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction;      nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:524)
at     org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.findByNamePatternPaged(Unknown Source)
at datapagedquery.service.TestCustomerService.testFindByPatternPaged(TestCustomerService.java:36)
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
... 33 more
```

Using   `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` annotation on the repository method works fine again from the transactional context.

After a while of debugging, it seems that the problem caused in 
`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery`, in `doCreateCountQuery()`, and `hasNamedQuery()`:

```
@Override
protected TypedQuery<Long> doCreateCountQuery(Object[] values) {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<Long> countQuery = null;

    if (hasNamedQuery(em, countQueryName)) {
        countQuery = em.createNamedQuery(countQueryName, Long.class);
    } else {
        Query query = createQuery(values);
        String queryString = extractor.extractQueryString(query);
        countQuery = em.createQuery(QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(queryString, countProjection), Long.class);
    }

    return createBinder(values).bind(countQuery);
}   
private static boolean hasNamedQuery(EntityManager em, String queryName) {

    try {
        em.createNamedQuery(queryName);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOG.debug("Did not find named query {}", queryName);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It tries to create a `TypedQuery` from the generated name `Customer.findByNamePattern.count`, which does not exist in the EntityManager's named query repository. The `hasNamedQuery()` checks it, catches the thrown  `IllegalArgumentException`,
and creates it on another way. The problem is that although the  `IllegalArgumentException` is caught, the transaction is rolled back (sometimes!)

I found the following workarounds:

1. using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` annotation on the repository method
2. OR- creating another named query

   ```
   @NamedQuery(
       name = "Customer.findByNamePattern.count",
       query = "select count(c.id) from Customer c where c.name like :pattern"
   ),
   ```

Which is not clear for me:

- calling `findAll()` should cause the same issue, but it doesnt. Why?
- using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` instead of `@NamedQuery` also does not cause the issue, why?
- How can I use @NamedQuery with pageable option, from a transactional context, to avoid the issue (and not to create explicitly the count query)?

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

used versions were:
Spring: 4.0.5.RELEASE
spring-data: 1.6.0.RELEASE, 1.7.0.RELEASE
Hibernate: 4.3.5.Final

After reading a similar bug at [https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-442], I downgraded hibernate version to 4.2.15.Final, which solved the issue. 
However a question is still alive, is it possible to solve the problem without changing Hibernate version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a PR with a potential fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/110
We use a new (throwaway) EntityManager for performing the named query lookup so that the original EntityManager will not be affected from a failed lookup.
As it turned out your problem is rather difficult to reproduce. Would you mind giving it a spin?
Perhaps you could even provide a small test case for this?

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your help, I've uploaded a small demo at https://github.com/sztgeza/springdata-pageable-query

Comment: Thank you very much for the test-case. Our changes for DATAJPA-617 seems to fix your problem. I created a small example with Spring Boot and the JPA version with the FIX: https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-data-bugs/tree/master/DATAJPA-617

Comment: Thomas, many thanks for the fix, it seems that it works now. May I ask, in which official release (and when) can we use the fix? Tx. again!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you run into is driven by multiple artifacts:

By definition a JPA `EntityManager` has to be closed (and potentially recreated) after it throws an exception. This is usually in place in case entity operations fail and you can be sure about the `EntityManager`s state. For a simple named query lookup this is quite strict as it surely doesn't need a new `EntityManager`created. However, we need to deal with that.

That said, we already work around this issue for manually defined queries (that's why you see it working for `@Query`). However, the defensive mechanism we introduced for [DATAJPA-350](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-350) we're not applied to the named query part. I've created [DATAJPA-617](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-617) for you.